# How do we create a SageMaker pipeline using AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, mlops

I have tried using the `AWS::SageMaker::Pipeline` resource in CloudFormation.

I want to give a pipeline definition in JSON format in CloudFormation. But there aren't any documentation available for that. There is documentation only for a Python SDK pipeline definition.

How can I create an *[MLOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MLOps) SageMaker* pipeline using CloudFormation?

Comment: the easiest way would be to create a pipeline using the Python SDK, then saving it as JSON, using the `definition()` function. https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/pipelines/sagemaker.workflow.pipelines.html#pipeline . Then either use that, or at least see how it works if you want to DIY. It's a complicated structure though...

Comment: Is the MLOps part relevant to the question (not a rhetorical question)?

Answer (score 1):

This process is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sagemaker-pipeline.html).

You can either construct the pipeline definition using the SageMaker Python SDK or by writing the JSON definition directly. The SDK makes it easier to define a pipeline and get the JSON definition.

Once you have the definition in JSON, you can define the pipeline in CloudFormation as it is documented in the link above.

Comment: Some example code (instead of a link that might break) would be helpful! :)